# Commiting the AngularJS Seed project to GIT with WebStorm has warnings

Tags: javascript, git, angularjs, warnings, webstorm

I have the AngularJS seed project open in Web Storm and an committing it to GIT, again using Web Storm.

When I click Commmit and Push I get 527 warnings.

The AngularJS plugin is installed, how to I exclude the AngularJS library from the commit and get rid of these warnings?

Thanks

**Update**

CrazyCoder's suggestion to declare AngularJS as a library has removed the warnings associated with that, however the web application is still causing warning to be shown.

For example, the controller has a warning that it is an unused function.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Ignoring files](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files).
2. Disable **Perform Code Analysis** in `Commit Project` dialog.

You can also store this library outside of the project roots and configure it as a [JavaScript Library](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/configuring-javascript-libraries.html).

Comment: Obviously, I don't want git to ignore them and I'd rather not have to disable code analysis as it's useful.  I've taken the third option, that makes sense, however there are still legitimate statements that warnings are being thrown for.  For example, my controller is marked as unused.

Comment: You can suppress certain warnings using Alt+Enter menu.